# Is there a way to get around having to reference Global variables inside a function in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to get around having to reference Global variables inside a function in PHP?

I just hate having to use the 'global' keyword for every variable, and I've been told that using constants (as an alternative) in PHP affects performance badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have to use many global variables inside of your function, something **has been designed wrong.**

Using even a few global variables considered bad practice, making code non-obvious.
And constants are not a solution despite of falseness of that "badly performance" rumor

If you need to use many variables inside of a function, consider array use

```
$data   = array("one","two","three");
$result = myfunc($data);
```

simple, reliable and readable

with more detailed explanation of what this function do and what all these variables for, you can get more precise answer.

Comment: What about all configuration variables? Aren't they stored in global variables? I dont think that placing configuration variables in global variables is wrongly designed.

I believe I'll have to start using the $GLOBALS['variable_name'] method instead.

Comment: @Basil configuration variables should be arranged into array in the first place! so, typing single `global $cfg;` wont hurt you too much

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just send the variable into the function like so:

```
function yourfunction ($variable1, $variable2) { 
    ... 

  }

 //Call the function:
 yourfunction ($variable1, $variable2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A singleton might be worth considering. Also see the registry pattern.

You could also factor out the global into its own function

This is very very basic...

`function do_stuff() {

  $var = get_something();

  //do more stuff

}`

function get_something() {
  return 'something';
}

Of course you'd need to set the variable too. That should be easy enough with an object or something.